# Using npm modules in Meteor Angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

This seems like a dumb question but I remain confused. Supposedly meteor has built in support for npm modules in 1.3 .

I am using Meteor with Angular integration. On the tutorial it seems that using npm modules should be as simple as:

1. installing the npm package into the meteor root folder

And

2. importing them into the file in the form `import name from 'name'`.

This however does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: That depends on the npm module (whether or not it produce a default export). The syntax for named export is `import { namedExport } from 'name';`. Can you post a minimal example that you think should work but doesn't? Does this also happen if you use "plain" Meteor (without Angular)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can think:

> does not seem to be working for me

may be the fact that not all packages produce default export as [MasterAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268093/masteram) mentioned.

For packages, that do not support default export you can use:
`import 'name'` to get your module loaded globally.